# error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git when using commitizen

Tags: git, commitizen

Now I want to using commitizen to commit the git repo in linux `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` , first install the commitizen(`Node v16.14.2`):

```
npm install -g commitizen
```

when I commit code using commitizen like this:

```
cz commit
```

show error like this:

```
error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `git cz` instead of `cz c` or `cz commit`. It works for me.